# C - Pointing to a character

Tags: c

I am trying to have a pointer point to a character, and then another pointer pointing to the first pointer, making both of them have the same values stored.

```
char ch = 'A';
char *cPtr1, *cPtr2;
cPtr1 = &ch;
cPtr2 = cPtr1;
printf("cPtr1 Stored:%c  Point:%x   Memory:%x\n", cPtr1, *cPtr1, &cPtr1);
printf("cPtr2 Stored:%c  Point:%x   Memory:%x\n", cPtr2, *cPtr2, &cPtr2);
```

The issue is that everytime I run it, it stores a different character and always points to '41'. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You've got the arguments to printf out of order.  `*cPtr1` will give you the character pointed to by `cPtr1` while `cPtr1` will give you the address being pointed to.

Comment: damn, thank you. so this means that,
*Pointer = Value
Pointer = Address
&Pointer = Address of Pointer

Comment: Yup, you've got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a little mix-up with what to pass to `printf`. Here is what you are looking for:

```
printf("cPtr1 Stored:'%c'  Point:%p   Memory:%p\n", *cPtr1, (void*)cPtr1, (void*)&cPtr1);
printf("cPtr2 Stored:'%c'  Point:%p   Memory:%p\n", *cPtr2, (void*)cPtr2, (void*)&cPtr2);
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/OxXVfE)

As you can see, both `cPtr1` and `cPtr2` are pointing to the same character. Moreover, the two pointers are the same. Pointers themselves, however, occupy separate locations in memory.

Explanation of changes:

- You need to dereference pointers `*cPtr1` to print with `%c`
- You need to use `%p` to print a pointer
- When you print a pointer, you need to cast the argument to `(void*)`.

Comment: What difference does it make to use %p instead of %x?

Comment: @VallyMan `%p` is standard-compliant for printing addresses; `%x` is not, even though it often works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're printing the address after "Stored:"

```
ch = 'A';
cPtr* = &ch;
printf("%x",cPtr); // Printing the pointer value(the address of the stored char).
printf("%c",*cPtr); // Printing the value which the pointer points to(dereferencing).
printf("%x",&cPtr); // Printing the address of the pointer itself.
```